# Can I share an HTML player?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I am trying to share a custom HTML/JavaScript player in Facebook. Is it possible?
I have tried with

```
    <meta property="og:video" content="https://***/player.html">
    <meta property="og:video:type" content="text/html">  
    <meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://***/player.html">
    <meta property="og:video:width" content="500">
    <meta property="og:video:height" content="500">
```

What I want to do is a system like the Twitter player cards. I wish to have my player embed in Facebook in an iframe (like Twitter). This way I can have a custom skin for my player and control it the way I want.

The code above is working if I link an MP3 file in secure_url & video but not when I link the player (example of link: `https://***/player.html`)

When shared on Facebook I have my link in a "video" element with the source set to my link.

Comment: No you can't. Only flash is possible

Comment: Thanks, 
for some reason my "Hello" was skiped .. Sorry about that.

Comment: @WizKid just sow thinglink.com and they do have a sharing with an iframe withing facebook. Tags on the page use the "og:video:type" -> "text/html" 

I can't find anything on that in the facebook documentation. Any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

well, youtube and soundcloud use html players for sharing. "https://www.youtube.com/embed/xPR-Ej-ENbk". So it should be possible, I am working on the same issue here, but when rendered on facebook am getting a div with class name "me-cannotplay", and am still trying to figure out if this something related to getting white listed by facebook or if there is something wrong with the html player i am using.

Comment: Hey, still looking for a solution just sow https://www.thinglink.com/
When you a share something you've done it display in an iframe. I tried to do the same (tags) but i get 'me-cannotplay" and no iframe ..

So it's possible but i cannot find any doc on it ...

Comment: We are testing a html5 feature with some sites like youtube and soundcloud.

Comment: Thanks, Is there a way to apply for it ?

Comment: Yup am also still working on it, but i got delayed because looks your player needs to be hosted over https (Secure protocol), otherwise it doesn't load. I tried using a player that is hosted on another site just for the testing, but i  got a link to download the file instead, am not sure what is the problem. When I get a chance to work on this I will repost here if I find a good solution

Comment: hi Khudairy, were you able to find a solution yet?

Comment: @RiteshKsheersagar, well we did everything as suggested by facebook ... at the end when sharing something it rendered like it is video, but then when you try to play it it gets replaced with a download link!. I am not sure of the reason, is it that we are not using streaming (we are just playing the file as is), or is it that only certain sites are allowed to render the player on facebook! not sure. Tried contacting some people at Facebook but with no response. If I every have updates I will post them here.

Answer (score 0):

As @WizKid said, a simple answer is that you just cannot embed any javascript in facebook story.